# Vue JS use index to build gap between elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

In my Vue JS project, I'm looping over some data and am outputting it to the page, however, I'm struggling to get the right gap between my elements using the `index` of an array item.

I need my elements to be evenly distributed at 5px apart, so it would go something like this:

- 0, 15, 30, 45 ...

I need to use the `index` because this is the only way that I can really space them apart, but at the moment whenever I try to use JS addition such as `index + .5` I end up with an odd result such as `1.5.025` rather than (for instance) `15.25`, what am I missing?

```html
<div class="uptime-timeline-wrapper" data-uptime-graph--wrapper>
  <svg height="30" version="1.1" :viewBox="`0 0 ${uptimeTimelineWidth} 30`" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="uptime-timeline">
    <rect
      v-for="(uptime, key, index) in monitor.charts.uptime.timeline"
      :key="index"
      v-b-tooltip.hover.top.html
      :title="`<div class='text-muted small'>${index+1} ${$moment.tz($moment(key), $auth.user.timezone).format('MMM Do, HH:mm')}</div>${uptime.uptime}`"
      aria-expanded="false"
      :fill="uptime.fill"
      fill-opacity="1"
      height="30"
      width="10"
      rx="3"
      ry="3"
      v-bind:x="`${index == 0 ? '0' : `${(index * 2)}0.25`}`"
      y="0">
    </rect>
  </svg>
</div>
```

I need to modify `v-bind:x="`${index == 0 ? '0' : `${(index * 2)}0.25`}`"` somehow.

Desired outcome:

```html
<svg>
  <rect x="0"></rect>
  <rect x="15"></rect>
  <rect x="30"></rect>
  <rect x="45"></rect>
  <rect x="60"></rect>
  // etc
</svg>
```

Comment: If you can explain what you're trying to achieve using a codesandbox, there might be a better way using only CSS

Comment: Also which index should generate `15.25`? What is the formula?

Comment: First  `<rect>` element needs `x="0"`, second `x="15"`, `x="30"`, `x="45"` etc

Comment: I think your going to sum string togethere, did you tried to convert them to number and then add them. Here: `${index === 0 ? 0}

Comment: When you use template literals, your numbers are converted to string.

Answer (score 2):

According to the comments,

> First  element needs x="0", second x="15", x="30", x="45" etc

I believe your calculation should simply be:

```
v-bind:x="index * 15"
```

This should generate 0, 15, 30, 45, and so on...